# HTML overflow-y

Tags: html, overflow

I've got a question with 100% height divs and overflow-y not working right in all browsers but Chrome...

Here's my test page: http://braido86.no-ip.com/playground/ui/

I have everything working perfectly fine in Chrome, then I went to test in other browsers only to find that scrollbars were not showing and the div's are going past the browsers boundaries. I've tested with Opera, Firefox, and IE. I've spent many hours playing around with this and googling for answers.

Is there something I'm missing to make this work in the other browsers, or was I just lucky that I got it to work in Chrome? Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow-y is a new feature, it might not work in all browsers. It's safer to user overflow: auto. Of course overflow: auto will add horizontal and vertical scrollbars so you need to make sure your inner content is narrow- for example:

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 350px; height: 400px">
  <div style="width: 300px; height: 2000px"> Content goes HERE
  </div>
</div>
```

And to emulate overflow-x you can use this:

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 350px; height: 400px">
  <div style="width: 3000px; height: 350px"> Content goes HERE
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad, I'm not actually using overflow-y. I am using overflow:auto, but I cannot set a specified height, it needs to be 100% so that the site always perfectly fits in your browser no matter the size.

Comment: @Snaggybore You can easily calculate it with jQuery, like: `$('#smth').height()`